# Adding object onto a specific field using an ID in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

In my database, every user will have a pages object, in those pages will be individual pages with different components in them and I am trying to push an object onto the component field by identifying which page to push to with an id.

Here is the code on my server side:

```
const { username, pageId, component } = req.body;

Post.update({ 'pages.page.page_id': pageId }, { $push: { contents: { component } } },
 (err, result) => {
   err ? console.log(err) : console.log(result);
 });
```

And here is what my database looks like:

```
"page": {
    "id": "5d4d930505b14fad02608242"
    "date_created": "01/20/19"
    "contents": {
        "component": {
            "text_content": {
                "paragraph": "value here",
            }
            "position": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
            }
            "size" : {
                "width": 200,
                "height": 200,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting the object to be pushed into the contents field of my selected page.

Comment: Wouldn't `component` be an array of objects? You can also use `$set` instead of push.

Comment: Yeah, component consists of a text object, position object, and size object. I tried set but I still get the same message : "{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }" and no change to the database.